# Reading multiple lines from QTextedit

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyparsing

I'm trying to write my own code-editor, I figure its a good way to learn pyQt.
I am using a qtextedit, in which i can write code(it's not real code, more pseudo code). 
Each line represents ending in a semi-colon represents some command
e.g.

```
PSEUDO->FWD->90;
PSEUDO->STOP;
PSEUDO->RIGHT 90;
PSEUDO->FWD 10;
```

These are relatively easy to read, as the user presses the [ENTER] the current line is read, parsed and checked for errors so the following

```
PSEUDO->RIGHT -pi/2
```

would generate an error because the line doesn't end in a semi-colon and the value following RIGHT needs to be a number.(my editor, my rules).All this I have more or less got working.

I would like to know how to do multiple lines though. I am familiar with editors such as Eclipse,sublime or visual studio which handle muliple lines very well, in my case

```
PSEUDO->DO:
FWD->90
RIGHT->45
FWD->10
LEFT->55
FWD->50
STOP;
```

Should all be read in and treated as one statement, starting at the keyword PSEUDO and ending at the semi-colon.
However the following should be read as 3 separate statements.

```
PSEUDO->DO:
FWD->90
RIGHT->45
FWD->10
LEFT->55
FWD->50
STOP;

PSEUDO->DO:
FWD->90
RIGHT->45
STOP;

PSEUDO->BACK 10;
```

My question how can I go about reading muliple lines as described above from QTextEditor as discreet statements.
Should I do the parse/check whenever I press the [ENTER] key for a new line?

I'm using python2.7,pyQT, and QTextEdit.

Comment: Have you considered using [QScintilla](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do, can be done with all the text of the document and some regular expressions.  I would be careful with this course, because it may slow things down.

So to stay lean and to use the right classes of Qt, I would use anything related to the Rich Text Processing, `QTextDocument`, and `QTextCursor`.

I have used `QSyntaxHighlighter` quite a bit, and `QRegExp`.  There is now `QRegularExpression`, too.  Here are the classes and general documentation I'd look at to get started with Rich Text processing.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-structure.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-cursor.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-common-tasks.html#finding-text

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should be really explicit that regular expressions will only work as long as the syntax remains a regular syntax. It's rather easy to turn a syntax into a non-regular one.

Comment: Thanks, not quite sure I fully understand how a regular expression helps. I can already use the pyparsing library to parse statements, and that works fine. I guess what i want to know is how to keep track of what's being entered so I can determine when it makes sense to start parsing. I don't think I want to parse the entire contents of the Qtextedit unnecessarily. How can I use a regular expression for this?